# Explorer.exe crashing/desktop flickering when running Hyper-V in fullscreen mode

Tags: windows-10, fullscreen, hyper-v

Anyone know how to fix explorer crashes/desktop flickering when running Hyper-V in fullscreen mode (host Windows 10 preview build 14291/vm OpenSuse Leap 42.1) resolution 1680*1050

GPU is the standard Intel HD Graphics 2500 on Intel Core i3-3220

Motherboard is ASUS P8B75-M LE

See video:

[Youtube](https://youtu.be/7Uz2Kp_sTwc)

Answer (score 0):

Build 14295 was just released, after I installed it the problem went away.